# 2FA code sent to wrong unknown number (Iran)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I forgot my passcode and kept entering wrong ones.  In the end, I reset the phone and reinstalled the latest iOS (13.3.1).

Now on startup, it sends a 2FA code to a number I have never seen and it's not in the format of my country (Iran).

When I bought the phone (iPhone 6S), I put in my SIM card for the 2FA. I have received codes from Apple before on this same number. Now it's changed and I receive the error:  "Your request could not be completed because of an error. Try again later."

This has been happening for hours so it's not due to low server capacity.

Comment: Contact Apple!...

Comment: No Apple support in Iran.

Comment: Call their US support number instead

Comment: @Madara you can choose "other Middle East". https://support.apple.com/en-mide/HT204921

Comment: Please describe how you fixed it so that others can benefit!

Comment: @jksoegaard It's not really a trick. When I said I had reset the phone and that I had never changed my number, it was before sanctions were reimposed on Iran in 2018. After that, Apple again dropped Iran from the list so I got a US number from the app TextNow and replaced the number I had given to Apple. I remembered this 3 hours ago, so I logged back in to TextNow on another phone and the number was there plus 2 already-sent codes from Apple. So I asked for another code and logged in. Good thing they hadn't deleted my account yet. Thanks again guys.

Comment: Madara,  I removed the update which contained the answer to your particular issue as answers belong in the answer section, not the question itself. Please post a separate answer, which you can then accept and increase your reputation and other can up-vote it too.

Comment: @user3439894 I understand but this was not a solution to the particular question I asked. The question I asked has no solution. I just missed out a fact which was mentioned as part of the issue. So the question doesn't exist because I did have that number I had just forgotten it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to begin the [account recovery process](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204921) with Apple. Nobody on this site can help you change your 2FA settings or reset your password because this site is not run by Apple Employees.